# How to debug from cmd on vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd

I don't know how to debug a code from Windows cmd. Bcuz my terminal (in vs code) is pixelated and I don't know what to do about it. By the way, I tried everything such as changing terminal font and font size.

Comment: see this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

Answer (score 0):

1. First create a **launch.json** file for your python project

   [image]

   [image]
2. then use the play button in the picture to start debugging the code.

   [image]

***You can configure how to debug in more detail in the **launch.json** file.***